# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: bid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to customize my bid_params to add a parameter to the database, my strong parameters are not working for some reason. I need to be able to have the current_user passed into the database on the creation of a bid. This object is nested in a has_many belongs_to relationship with Auctions. Here is my controller:

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bids = @auction.bids
  end

  def new
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bid = @auction.bids.build
  end

  def create
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bid = @auction.bids.create(bid_params)
    if @bid.save
      flash[:success] = "Bid has been successfully placed."
      redirect_to @auction
    else
      flash[:error] = @bid.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
     @bid = @auction.bids.find
    @bid.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed Bid."
    redirect_to auction_url(@bid.article_id)
  end

  private

  def bid_params
    params.require(:bid).permit(:auction_id).merge(bidder: current_user)
  end

end
```

and Stack Trace:

```
Started POST "/auctions/2/bids" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-06 08:54:35 -0600
Processing by BidsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6x4hV8y323a10kaJN5Rubj1z3uhUrSDQrD6aoaWCUhk=", "commit"=>"Create Bid", "auction_id"=>"2"}
  Auction Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "auctions".* FROM "auctions"  WHERE "auctions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: bid)
```

New Form:

```
<h1>Create a New Bid</h1>
<%= form_for ([@auction, @bid]) do |f|%>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<%end%>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at parameters that controller received:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6x4hV8y323a10kaJN5Rubj1z3uhUrSDQrD6aoaWCUhk=", "commit"=>"Create Bid", "auction_id"=>"2"}
```

And then you try to permit these params:

```
def bid_params
  params.require(:bid).permit(:auction_id).merge(bidder: current_user)
end
```

And error was thrown in this operation: `params.require(:bid)` as this method suppose your params looks like:

```
{ ..., "bid" => { "auction_id" => "2" } }
```

Hence you may change your view/js that sends params or change `def bid_params` implementation to:

```
def bid_params
  params.permit(:auction_id).merge(bidder: current_user)
end
```

Comment: Ah! I see. I will check and see if that works in a couple hours. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It worked! Nice catch Alexander. Have a good rest of the weekend